# Pages 5.1 underlines some words as misspelled, but does not allow me to "Ignore/Learn Spelling"

Tags: pages, iwork

I am using Pages 5.1. When I misspell words, spellchecker underlines them in red. I am usually able to either "Ignore Spelling" or "Learn Spelling" when I right-click the word:

[image: ignore/learn option available]

But for some words, those options do not appear despite spellchecker underlining them in red:

[image: ignore/learn option unavailable]

This can be particularly annoying when I use recurring names. Why can't I "Ignore Spelling" or "Learn Spelling" on these words? And is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I create technical papers, and many words are not recognized by spellchecker. Some words can be learned using control-click but most can't be used at all until added to the dictionary. This is very annoying and time-consuming.

The one things that helps me add words is to use the arrow cursor keys to move the insertion point to the end of the word or past the space and then back a space to "jog" the software into letting you add the word.

If that fails, quitting the app or restarting is sometimes effective.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is nothing you can do because it is not a misspelled word!

If it needs no editing, does it matter whether spellcheck recognizes words or not?

It is just indicating that word since it is not a part of normal vocabulary giving you chance to look it up since there are multiple Meinhard out there.

However:

On a Mac with OS X one can add or remove custom words which are located in the

> ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary

Comment: If it is not misspelled, why is it underlined in red?

Comment: Good point it should use different color, but it is just trying to bring it up to your attention, since it is not offering spelling but the use of the www look up it tells you what to do or not. Did you try entering that word in your custom directory ?